# ORA-01847 - error while adding an uncorrelated AND clause

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I'm trying to make a very simple query and I'm getty crazy over it cause I keep getting this error:

> ora-01847 day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

This is the query

```
select *
  from TAB1 H 
  JOIN TAB2 D ON D.PAR2 = H.PAR1
  where TO_DATE(D.DATE, 'dd-mm-yyyy') <> sysdate
  and  H.FIELD = 'TEST';
```

What's weird is that if I take any of the two AND clause away, it'll work flowless. It will also work if, instead of using the last AND clause to retrieve some record , I pass their id directly so I don't think it's a problem of date format or anything else.

Both D.DATE and H.FIELD are defined as VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)

Any head up?

EDIT:
[Actual dates that are causing issues]

```
01/10/2017
01/10/2018
01/10/2018
01/10/2017
01/05/2023
01/05/2023
01/05/2023
01/05/2023
01/05/2023
01/10/2017
01/05/2018
01/02/2018
```

!!!> While scrolling down to get this samples, it gave me that error again. I can only guess that it happened once arrived at a row with a 'TEST' value in the column

EDIT:

```
 select H.*
      from TAB1 H 
      JOIN TAB2 D ON D.PAR2 = H.PAR1
      where TO_DATE(D.DATE, 'dd-mm-yyyy') <> sysdate;
```

Will gave the same error. Eliminating the where clause or selecting everything will "solve" the problem though.

EDIT:

```
select ID as ID, null as ID_REF
    from TAB1
    where FIELD = 'TEST'
  union all
  select NULL as ID, ID_REF as ID_REF
  from TAB2
  where TO_DATE(DATE, 'dd-mm-yyyy') <> sysdate;
```

This, scrolling down (and allegedly reaching a record while the two conditions lik), will give the same error.

Comment: Can you provide some sample date values from D.date column?

Comment: Just did, I also added an hint that might help you guys!

Comment: Perhaps `<> trunc(sysdate)`?

Comment: Nope. I'm adding another edit about the behavior, hoping it'll help..

Comment: `What's weird is that if I take any of the two AND clause away, it'll work flowless`  What is the error/issue?

Comment: What do you mean?
I need the two clauses to coexist. Whit that sentence I was pointing out that it's neither of the clauses the cause the errors, but their coworking :)

Comment: @pedro - it would probably help immensely if you included the text of the error message - just in case somebody hasn't memorized the oracle error codes - you only reference the code once in your title and then you're repeatedly saying "same error" but it may not be obvious what error you're dealing with.

Comment: You're very right, added it even though I don't think that error is the actual problem..

Comment: Why on earth are you storing dates in a `VARCHAR` column. Your current problem is a direct result of that broken design.

Comment: What Andrew was hitting at: `<> sysdate` is not going to do what you think it does. `sysdate` includes the current time. Whereas a varchar converted to a date using `'dd-mm-yyyy'` will have the time set to `00:00:00`

Comment: That's just a staging table, I only need it for collecting datas uploaded from forms. Sysdate is just a placeholder, in the actual query I have another date passed from another form. I still don't get why, if the problem is that being a varchar, it gives no error taking the FIELD = 'TEST' clause away..

Comment: the date 01/02/2018 in your sample set above has a non display character at the end.  (or at least your copy/paste does.)  if I copy the dates above paste into word and enable the paragraph marks ¶ I see a symbol which is not end of paragraph on the date 1/2/2018  It could be this non-display character causing the issue.  Can you update this table column so that it is just 1/2/2018 w/o the non-display character (if it exists)

Comment: That most certainly was the issue. I can't tell for sure because I truncated the table and loaded it again with other data and now it works.
Since there was no other reason for it not to work, if you report your comment as a question I'll elect it as the answer :)

Comment: APC put you on the right path.. The function would have identified this record  (just my 2 cents)

Comment: Fak I totally missed the edit :o
Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message for `ORA-01847` is

> day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

So the obvious candidate is

```
> where TO_DATE(D.DATE, 'dd-mm-yyyy') <> sysdate
```

That is, you have values in `D.DATE` which contain strings that can't be cast to a date, such as `'32-05-2017'`. This is always a risk when we use a VARCHAR column to hold a date - or a number.

> "I scroll through the result set, as soon as it load the 100+th results, it blows"

Yes, that was what my questions about fetching were driving at. Clearly you have duff data (non-dates) in the `d.date` column: filtering on `h.field` simply brought the duff to the top of the result set quicker than scrolling through the whole table did.

You can investigate the scale of the rot with a function like this:

```
create or replace function is_date
      (p_date_str in varchar2
        , p_date_fmt in varchar2 := 'dd-mm-yyyy' )
     return varchar2
as
    return_value varchar2(20);
    l_date date; 
begin
    begin
        l_date := to_date(p_date_str, p_dae_fmt);
        return_value := 'DATE';
    exception
        when others then
            return_value := 'NOT A DATE';
    end;
    return return_value;
end; 
/
```

This query will return the records you need to ponder:

```
select d.id -- or whatever
        , d.date
from tab2 d
where is_date(d.date) = 'NOT A DATE'
/
```

What you do next rather depends on the nature and quantity of the duffness you discover. That problem may well merit a new question.

Comment: That has been my first check and, as I stated in the opening question, I don't really think that's the case because I tried passing the records ID instead of using and AND clause and it works just fine.

Anyway, I'll add in the opening question the whole set of dates that should come out after crossing the clauses.

Comment: @pedro . . . Tis is obviously the problem.  You just haven't yet seen the offending date column.

Comment: Edited the opening question, I still don't see how that's the problem though!
If it's a varchar -to-date problem then why don't I get the error while taking the FIELD = 'TEST' clause away?

Comment: You have fetched **the entire result set** without the `FIELD = 'TEST' ` filter?

Comment: Yes, if I take the date clause away (leaving only the join and the FIELD = 'TEST' clause), it doesn't give any problem

Comment: So there's no problem with **the entire table** but there's a problem with a subset of its records??? That seems unlikely. But if you say that's what's happening then I guess it must be. However the lessons of history are that when someone posts a question on StackOverflow asking "why is this weird thing happening?" it's usually because of the difference between what they think their environment is and what their environment actually is.

Comment: Just to throw in some more intel, I took the whole FIELD='TEST' clause away and, having just the join and the to_date clause, it will run and give me a result.
However, if I scroll through the result set, as soon as it load the 100+th results, it blows.

Now that's changes a lot of things and tells me the problem is not liked to the FIELD = 'TEST' clause.
Should I edit the op or, since it's a pretty big change, should I just close this question and open a new one?

Comment: As I said, I can't tell for sure what the problem was because I truncated the table and filled it again. That solved the issue.
Anyway, I'm picking yours as the best answer :)